# How to set a custom page size in Numbers?

Tags: numbers, iwork

There seems to be no option for this on Numbers 4.2

There are a bunch of options with fixed sizes, but nothing to set custom values for the document's width and height.

The reason is that I want to export the spreadsheet as a document with the size being roughly the same as the screen on my tablet, so that I don't have to scroll horizontally or vertically to see all its contents, nor to have black bars on both sides of the page, so to maximize the information I can fit in the document.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to print a custom sized PDF or do you actually have paper that size?  There is the content scale to fit to a page such as A4 or US Letter.  Please clarify in your question.  Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: @bjbk Thanks for pointing that out. I added a more detailed description with my purpose for having a custom size.